# Is it possible to block keyboard input selectively in Windows? How?

Tags: c#, windows

My app (in C#) need to interface with a USB bar-code scanner, which is basically working like a keyboard. It inputs the bar-code with an enter key at the end.

The app need to be work even when it's at background, so I am using low level keyboard hook to get and filter the bar-code out in the global key events. This part is already working.

**Here is my problem: I don't want other apps to get the keyboard(scanner) inputs if it is a bar-code. And the normal key events should not be interfered. In one word, block the key events selectively.** Is this possible?

My app is in C#, but I have no problem with C++ or more native solutions as long as it's easy to integrate in C#.

Thanks.

Additional Information：

1. The whole idea is working at background, even when it's not active. It watches the global key events stream and spot the bar-code sequence (already implemented with Hook). And most importantly, it do NOT interfere with normal keyboard events nor other applications' operation. That's why I cannot block all the key events or make it top-most.
2. I already can get the bar-code. I need to prevent other applications from getting the bar-code.

Comment: So basically you want to make your app to be "top most" in keystrokes handling?

Comment: @Justin That's not the problem. I can already filter the barcode out.

Comment: @AKFish My Bad - I'll actually read the question properly...

Comment: @Reniuz No. The app cannot be top most. It need to be working when it's not active. And most importantly, not messing other applications up at the same time.

Comment: @Justin Not at all. Thanks for your concern to my problem.

Comment: I mean "top most"(first by priority) of all apps in **listening** for keyboard inputs. After your app decides that input is not barcode lets other apps use the input.

Comment: was reading about low level keyboard hooks and got into Raw Input, at first glance it seems to be better for your need then a hook.

Comment: You will want to intercept at OS level rather than just relying it of being top most window. See my post below

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your keyboard hook you would call [CallNextHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644974%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to execute next hook in the chain.

I would suggest that put some unique signature as a preamble for your barcode so that your keyboard hook procedure can detect it as a valid barcode input from your scanner. Now, when you get this data, just skip the call to 'CallNextHookEx' so that the chain will be discontinued and other programs won't get your barcode. Otherwise - call 'CallNextHookEx' so the chain can continue.

Note: This is my theory, I have never tried the exact same thing myself. I have however, written hooks in C++ and C#.

Answer (score 0):

Check this project out
http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/

It is in C# as well so will make your coding easier. Sounds like all you need is to hook up the global key press event and suppress it by setting the Handled value or something similar.